# Call method in data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

How do I bind the return of a method into a TextView?

Sample:

```
class U {
    final String a = "x", b = "ddd";

    String message(){
        return a + " " + b;
    }
}
```

So trough data binding I wanna display the return from message()

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

**1 - In your Activity:**

```
YourLayoutBinding mBinding; //this type of class is auto-generated by AS based on the name of your layout.xml

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_layout);
    mBinding.setU(new U());
}
```

**2 - And inside your layout:**

```
<data>
    <variable name="u" type="U" />
</data>

<TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"                         
      android:text="@{u.message}"
      android:textColor="#000"/>
```

Comment: And the class and the method must be public as well.

Comment: What is "message" in `u.message`? Where is the method?